# VBA - With/End With Add only 2 Sheets

Tags: vba, excel, with-statement

I have written the following code:

```
Sub CreateSheet()
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "ClientList"
        .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "ProviderList"
    End With
End Sub
```

My problem is the following: after the code creates the two sheets, I want it to stop and create no other sheets even if I run it again. I want to add 2 and only 2 sheets!
What it does now is to create those two sheets and if I run it again it will try to create other sheets and I get the error message saying "The name is already taken. Try a different one." 
Could you please help me?

Comment: Write a function that checks if a sheet exists and create only when the function returns False (it doesn't exist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's different aproach:

```
Sub CreateSheet()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In Sheets
        'if we have already sheet with given name, then exit sub (means no adding new sheets)
        If sh.Name = "ClientList" Or sh.Name = "ProviderList" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "ClientList"
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "ProviderList"
End Sub
```

It's not necessary to use `With ThisWorkbook` as this is default workbook to use when workbook reference isn't used.

Comment: *'as this is default workbook to use when workbook reference isn't used.'* - not if it isn't the activeworkbook.

Comment: Hm, I think I understand remark, but not fully... That's way I avoid using `ActiveWorkbook` etc. :) And use refernces.

Comment: Thank you, Michał Turczyn! It works and, indeed, the code is simpler!

Comment: ... and what if you have a *ClientList* worksheet but not a *ProviderList* worksheet (or vice versa)?

Comment: @Jeeped It's based on assumption, that these sheets can only be added together.

Comment: I'm not saying it's bad code and your assumptions may well be correct; I was just pointing out potential logic flaws for future viewers of your solution.

Comment: @Jeeped I totally agree with you. I just made clarification, so OP won't be confused (that's why upvoted all your comments).

Answer (score 2):

You can save all worksheet names in an array `SheetNamesArr`, and afterwards check if the sheet name, for instance "ClientList" is found within the array that holds all sheet names.

You can check if "ClientList" already exists in the array by using `Application.Match` function:

```
If IsError(Application.Match("ClientList", SheetNamesArr, 0)) Then
```

If `IsError` will result to `True` it means this worksheet doesn't exist yet, and you can safely add it, otherwise do nothing.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateSheet()

Dim i As Long
Dim SheetNamesArr() As String

ReDim SheetNamesArr(100) ' redim to large size, will optimize size later

For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    SheetNamesArr(i - 1) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
Next i
ReDim Preserve SheetNamesArr(0 To i - 2) ' resize to size of populated sheet names

With ThisWorkbook
    ' using Match, means if IsError sheet name not found in current array of sheet names >> you can add it
    If IsError(Application.Match("ClientList", SheetNamesArr, 0)) Then
        .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "ClientList"
    End If
    ' same as previous Match
    If IsError(Application.Match("ProviderList", SheetNamesArr, 0)) Then
        .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "ProviderList"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Shai Rado. The code you provided along with the explanations work and made me understand the proper logic/syntax.